# What's the Difference between "Content Values" and "Content Objects"

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I'm exploring bindings right now, and have an NSPopUpButton -

It presents me a number of options for bindings under Value Selection - `Content`, `Content Objects`, `Content Value`s, and then `Selected Object`, `Selected Value,` and `Selected Tag`. Could someone please explain the difference between these?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Those are explained in the [Cocoa Bindings Reference for NSPopUpButton](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSPopUpButton.html), although that reference is not quite clear.

`Content` is an array controller that provides elements to the popup button. The array controller should be bound to an array. In order to determine how each element in the array is shown in the popup button, `-description` is sent to each object in the array.

You may customise this in two ways:

- If you want the `Selected Object` binding to provide an object distinct from the array elements managed by the array controller to which `Content` was bound, you can bind `Content Objects` to another array controller. It could also be the same array controller but with a different key path;
- If you want the popup button options to be something different than the description of each element in the array managed by the array controller to which `Content` was bound, you can bind `Content Values` to another array controller that manages an array whose elements contain the popup options. It could also be the same array controller but with a different key path.

A simple example: suppose you have the following class:

```
@interface Customer : NSObject
@property (copy) NSString *name;
@property (copy) NSString *phoneNumber;
@end
```

and you haven’t overridden the `-description` method. In this case, `-description`is useless and the `name` property would be a good choice for the popup options. You’d bind:

- `Content` to an array controller that manages an array of `Customer` instances, controller key `arrangedObjects`;
- `Content Values` to the same array controller, controller key `arrangedObjects`, model keypath `name`.

You can then bind `Selected Object` to something else, for example a property in your application delegate or window controller. Cocoa bindings would then assign the selected `Customer` instance to that property.

Now suppose you are not interested in the whole `Customer` object that’s been selected, but only its phone number. In this case, you can bind `Content Objects` to the same array controller, controller key `arrangedObjects`, model keypath `phoneNumber`. When a popup option is selected, Cocoa bindings will set `phoneNumber` instead of an entire `Customer` instance. In summary: if you don’t bind `Content Objects`, `Selected Object` represents the original object in the array. If you bind `Content Objects`, then `Selected Object` can be something different.

You’d bind `Selected Value` if you were not interested in the original objects (or the content objects), but the actual strings shown in the popup options according to the `Content Values` bindings.

Quick recipe for providing data to the popup button:

- Bind `Content` if you have objects (not only strings) that represent the popup options;
- Bind `Content Values` if the options that are shown to the user cannot be obtained via `Content` by sending `-description` to the array elements;
- Bind `Content Objects` if you want `Selected Object` to return something different from the array elements from `Content`.

Quick recipe for obtaining the current selection in a popup button:

- Bind `Selected Object` if you want to know the full object (either from `Content` or `Content Objects`) representing the current popup selection;
- Bind `Selected Value` if you only want the string that’s currently selected in the popup.

And lastly, you’d use `Selected Tag` if the popup options are actually taken from a menu whose items have a tag set.

Comment: Fantastic answer! Where were people like you when I was learning this stuff?

Comment: Wow - that made everything a lot clearer! I did read the docs before asking the question, but they didn't help - thank you for the comprehensive explanation.

Comment: Quick, almost unrelated question - if I wanted to bind the button with the same array controllers "current selection", how would I go about doing that? I get an <NSControllerObjectProxy> showing up in the button if I try binding 'Selected Object' to 'selection' - maybe I'm not understanding it correctly.

Comment: @Nano8Blazex As you’ve noticed, `selection` doesn’t return the original object — it returns a proxy object instead. You need to bind the popup button’s `Selected Index` to the array controller’s `selectionIndex`.

Comment: Very good answer. What would I have to do if I indeed want to bind `Selected Object` to the whole object (for assignment), but want to display not the output of `description` but a custom property?

Answer (score 3):

`#Object` refers to any KVC-compliant object. `#ObjectValue` refers to the key path used to get the value from that object.

So, for your pop-up binding, ContentObjects would be bound to, say, an `NSArrayController`'s `arrangedObjects`. Say this refers to an array of dictionaries or managed objects. You can't meaningfully present a dictionary in a pop-up (you get the start of the `description` output, e.g `<NSCFDictionary...` or similar), so this is where the contentValues binding comes in. This would be something like your NSArrayController's `arrangedObjects.name`, where name is a key from your dictionary or managed object.

I hope this helps, I struggled with the same concept myself when I started with bindings.